# PHP FPM and Nginx dockerfile

Tags: php, nginx, dockerfile, fpm

I have this dockerfile that contains my php fpm and nginx together:

```
# Use a base image that includes PHP and Nginx
FROM php:8.2-fpm AS symfony-app

# Install any additional dependencies needed for your Symfony application
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    vim curl debconf subversion git apt-transport-https apt-utils \
    build-essential locales acl mailutils wget nodejs zip unzip \
    gnupg gnupg1 gnupg2 \
    sudo \
    ssh \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo pdo_pgsql \
    soap \
    zip \
    opcache \
    gd \
    intl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Set up your Symfony application
COPY . /var/www/online-invitations
RUN mkdir -p /var/www \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/.composer \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.composer
WORKDIR /var/www/online-invitations

# Specify the path to the auth.json file using the COMPOSER_AUTH environment variable
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN composer install --no-interaction --no-progress --prefer-dist \
    && npm install

# Configure Nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nginx \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server 127.0.0.1:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80

# Define your entrypoint
COPY bin/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Start both PHP-FPM and Nginx
CMD ["entrypoint.sh", "php-fpm"]
```

Now my default.conf is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/online-invitations/public;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\\.php(/|$) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

        internal;
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it runs just fine, I can see that my pod exposes these ports:

```
0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 9000/tcp
```

But when I try to access it I get `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`. Anyone knows why? I have tried using different port, for example 8080:80 or something else but fails with same exception.

For reference this is my docker-compose.yml part for fpm:

```
  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/online-invitations/:cached
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: database
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_DB: online-invitations
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    entrypoint: ["entrypoint.sh", "php-fpm"]
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this problem really related to PHP itself?

Comment: So before I had split nginx and fpm, and things were working fine. So I wanted to switch from separate nginx and fpm pods to a single one. This is when this problem started happening. This was my previous nginx dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server fpm:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

All the rest stayed the same. So I can't figure it out

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. You haven't shared any configuration that is "splitted"

Comment: My question is not about "splitted" configuration ,it's about my current problem? I am just saying that before this dockerfile I had 2 dockerfiles, one for fpm and one for nginx. Now I combined them and started seeing this issue. In my comment I gave you what my previous nginx dockerfile had, and that's all it had. Everything else stayed the same

Comment: @vukojevicf are you sure nginx is started properly? In nginx:latest image, it has "nginx -g daemon off" as the startup cmd, how do you start nginx in your 'combined' dockerfile?